# How to Pass Username and Password in GET Request in Java

Tags: java, httpclient

Below is the Code Written by me.
But when i send the request i am getting Response Code 401 : Unathorized.

```
    String url = "SAMPLE_URL";
    URL obj = new URL(url);

    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    //add request header
    //con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to your program after `obj.openConnection();`

```
String encoded = Base64.encode(username+":"+password);
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);
```

Comment: I tried the Solution provided by Still got the same response: Response Code : 401
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: <MYURL>at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)

Comment: Can you acces the url with the user/password in a browser?

Comment: Yes i can access the URL in the browser.

Comment: Worked for me, just need a tweak: `String encoded = Base64.encode((username+":"+password).getBytes());`